# Group by in SSRS (row grouping) vs SQL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Sample data:

```
CID | CName 
------------
1   | Rob   
1   | Rob   
1   | Rob   
2   | Tim   
2   | Tim   
2   | Tim
```

Expected Output:

```
CID | CName 
1   | Rob   
2   | Tim
```

1. Add table -> drag CID on the table -> drag CName on the table
2. Rt click on the details row group and select the grouping as CID

This works fine. I come from a SQL background where we have to place every non aggregate column in the group by clause. Where as in ssrs like the example above, is it sufficient to place any one column for the grouping. Am I getting this right?

So effectively is it right to say that the grouping is based on the CID and only the 1st CName for that CID is getting displayed on the row. And say if there was a 3rd column with unique values, then if we drag that column on the above table, then only the 1st of the value per grouping (grouping on CID in this example) will be shown is this correct?

Is there any guideline as to - when we can replace the details group with row group and when we must add a parent row group to a detail group?

Answer (score 0):

As with a lot of things, there are several solutions to a problem and several ways to answer some of your questions. here's a few notes that may be useful.

Grouping in SSRS primarily for aggregating data. In your sample data, which does not really have anything to aggregate (other than maybe a count) then you could achieve the expected out put by either.

1. Changing the query to do a SELECT DISTINCT, the table would only need a details row to display
2. Grouping as you described, although the 'details' row is then no longer a details row (the icon will change to indicate this) as you have added grouping.
3. Adding a parent group and delete the details row

As for your question

> " Where as in ssrs like the example above, is it sufficient to place
>   any one column for the grouping. Am I getting this right?"

The answer is, "sort of". Technically you should group by both columns although the outcome will be the same. If you group by just the CID column for example then the CName textbox expression effectively becomes `=FIRST(Fields!Cname.Value)`, so it's actually doing an aggregation for you.

This would the equivalent of SQL statement

```
SELECT CID, Min(CName) AS CName FROM myTable GROUP BY CID
```

Hope this help clear things up.

**Update:**
In response to the revised question and comment

Basically it's taking the first value it finds with no guarantee of the order. In SQL terms it's like doing `SELECT top 1 myField FROM myTable` with no order clause so you have no way of knowning what data will be returned.

It's always best to group by both fields or specifically set the expression to use `FIRST'.

If you have a 3rd column with real details, then you would need two row groups, a details 'group' and a rowgroup that groups by CID and CName.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have since then modified the question area - please can you have a look and add it to the answer to I can mark it right

Comment: You have mentioned that "CName textbox expression effectively becomes =FIRST(Fields!Cname.Value)" - I was also expecting this to be shown in the textbox value so it is more understandable - but SSRS does not show it like that - I mean the wording FIRST(...